# Error encountering upon Maven project building

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite, m2e

I am encountering issues upon building the project I'm working in Spring Tool Suite. I kinda new in the Spring Tool Suite and Maven integration and I'm always getting the errors below

```
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'XXX'.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenRequiredCapability.<init>(MavenRequiredCapability.java:38)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenRequiredCapability.createMavenArtifact(MavenRequiredCapability.java:53)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:101)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.clean(MavenBuilder.java:211)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:736)
```

Also

```
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenRequiredCapability.<init>(MavenRequiredCapability.java:38)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.MavenRequiredCapability.createMavenArtifact(MavenRequiredCapability.java:53)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:101)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I think due to this most of my dependencies was encountering a failure to transfer issue. Am I missing any Maven setting or it's an existing in STS (Spring Tool Suite)?

Comment: this looks a bit like https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453995, but that seems to be fixed in m2e 1.6. What version of STS are you using? And can you provide a few steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @MartinLippert I just missed to update this issue. I fixed it already, it was the settings.xml in the Maven section is not configured in the correct directory location that's why it's throwing a NullpointerException.

Comment: ok, thanks for letting us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed already. This is due to the settings.xml in the Maven section of Spring Tool Suite is not configured to the correct directory location. That's why it's throwing a NullpointerException.